# Appropriate Navigation Property Usage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I know this is probably a very obtuse question, but do entities which represent a lookup table need navigation properties?

For example

```
public class State
{
    public int StateId      { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string StateAbbr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AccreditingAgency> AccreditingAgencies { get; set; }
}


public class AccreditingAgency
{
    public int AccreditingAgencyId { get; set; }
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }
    public string AgencyAddress { get; set; }
    public string AgencyCity { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string AgencyZipCode { get; set; }
    public string AgencyWebsite { get; set; }

    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in the example above, should I even have a State navigation property in AccreditingAgency?

In fact, when *should* a navigation property be used?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: A typical example of a circular reference structure that any Json/XML serializer would choke on.

Comment: So, I assume no then? Just curious since the Model First approach has this as a default for every entity. No tutorials I found really explain the navigation property all that well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation properties are purely there for your benefit.

If you want to be able to find out all Accrediting agencies in a state include the first nav property.

If you want to find out what state an accrediting agency is in include the second navigation property.

If you dont really want to know either of these then prehaps the two entities shoudlnt be linked at all.

Comment: Is the StateID field not enough to reference the state? Or must I have the State navigation property to load the State?

Comment: If you have a StateID it probably means you are navigating in one direction, if this is the case you should add in a navigation property so you can load the state from the stateID.